# How to set ServletMapping path pattern in context (Tomcat Context)

Tags: java, tomcat

I create a context and assign as tomcat context with urlpattern `/api`.
Now, I add `DefaultServlet` to Tomcat and create a filter and map for jersey resourceConfig.

```
Context context = tomcat.addContext("/api", base.getAbsolutePath());
Tomcat.addServlet(context, "default", new DefaultServlet());
context.addServletMapping("/*", "default");
final FilterDef def = new FilterDef();
final FilterMap map = new FilterMap();

def.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
def.setFilter(getJerseyFilter());
context.addFilterDef(def);
map.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
map.addURLPattern("/*");
context.addFilterMap(map);
tomcat.start();
```

---

```
private static Filter getJerseyFilter(){

    final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages(Main.class.getPackage().getName())

            // create instance of Resource and dynamically configure to ResourceConfig
            .register(new Resource(new Core(), configuration))

            .register(JspMvcFeature.class) // register jspMVC
            .property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);

    return new ServletContainer(config);
}
```

Now, I am successfully able to access `localhost:PORT/api/<end_point>`

Now my question is, I want to assign a path `/serve/*` in ServletMapping like

```
Tomcat.addServlet(context, "default", new DefaultServlet());
context.addServletMapping("/serve/*", "default");
```

Then I want to access the resource on `localhost:PORT/api/serve/<end_point>`

but it prompt error

```
HTTP Status 404 -    
type Status report   
message    
description The requested resource is not available.    
Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
```

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to access? Note /* and /abc map a servlet to different URLs.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens please check my updated question.